# error while search against the Scopus Search API and save the results in batches into a xml file

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest, scopus

I'm trying to extract abstract from Scopus, using rscopus and with the functions that I got from https://github.com/christopherBelter/scopusAPI

I have the API key using my university account, but when trying to save the data in xml, with:

`theXML <- searchByString(string = query, outfile = "testdata.xml")`

I got an error:

```
Error in searchByString(string = query, outfile = "testdata.xml") : Unauthorized (HTTP 401).
    3. stop(http_condition(x, "error", task = task, call = call))
    2. httr::stop_for_status(theURL) at scopusAPI.R#12
    1. searchByString(string = query, outfile = "testdata.xml")
```

Does something wrong with my API key since ": Unauthorized (HTTP 401)"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried validating your string outside of the script?

The Elsevier Developer Portal would be a good place to try out your string to confirm it works or to refine it so it works

```
"https://dev.elsevier.com/scopus.html"
```